# Disable a key python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard

Is there a way to disable a key input in python 3.4. For example if I wanted to make a program that stopped the user from using the enter key would I be able to do this.

Is there anything like:

```
disable(key_input_enter)
```

Comment: Disable the key for the entire system, or only for your program? Furthermore about what operating system are we talking?

Comment: Disabling the key from being used for the whole system. I am using windows 10.